# Pick the Initials in a csv in Linux

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

Is there a way in Unix to filter only Initials from a file that contains other texts too. Is it practical? (Apologize my poor wording)

```
input file

13 J JOHN
30 J
56 JACOB
29 JAKE
89 A
20 ALEX
12 A ARIEL
80 Z
34 Z ACK
67 K
```

Output:

```
30 J
89 A
80 Z
67 K
```

Comment: Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to produce a [mcve]. Show your own efforts is helpful for you to get good and timely answers.

Comment: You can do it, using a simple `awk` with a `substr` inside.

Comment: i wanted to get the test code done but i was worried whether it would make no sense to the developers out here. i tried many techinquies. thanks for your positive criticism. thank you all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the initial case (that no longer matches the question):

```
$ awk 'length($2) == 1' file
30 J
89 A
80 Z
67 K
```

**EDIT**: For the updated case:

```
$ cat file2
13 J JOHN
30 J
56 JACOB
29 JAKE
89 A
20 ALEX
12 A ARIEL
80 Z
34 Z ACK
67 K

$ awk 'NF == 2 && length($2) == 1' file2
30 J
89 A
80 Z
67 K
```

Comment: one question. what if my data is A ALEX, J JACOB... when i tried it on my data. it was cropping those records that had names like this.

Comment: Assuming you don't want to include ones like 'A ALEX', see edit.